# Setting background image to an application which already has a theme

Tags: android, background-image, android-theme

Hi i want to set background image to my application which already has a theme.

```
<application   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

Now i have changed the code to this

```
  <style name="BackgroundImage" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

the manifest file looks like this

```
 <application   android:theme="@style/BackgroundImage" />
```

Now the background image is set but my previous theme i.e. Theme.NoTitleBar is not working.

Ideal behavior expected is both background image and Theme.NoTitleBar should be working. What should i do?

Comment: i would say that the parent definition may be incorrect (@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar may be?)

Comment: No it is not the problem. Anyways i have made the changes you have mentioned and checked but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the style as follows by doing this i am overriding the Theme.NoTitlteBar

```
 <style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now manifest file looks like this.

```
<application  android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in the xml file, and not your manifest.

you just have to do somerhing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@drawable/yourimage" >   //your drawable image here
```

hope i helped you

Comment: Hii thanks for the reply. I would try this method later but i found my mistake and i will post my solution now.